# Reaction mechanism of phenylhydrazine with carbonyl

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

I am currently working on the following problem, but I don’t know how it is solved:

[image]

I guess it is a Fischer-Indol synthesis, but I am not sure. This is what I got:

[image]

Any help would really be appreciated^^

Comment: If your study of chemistry advanced to the level to address questions like the one presented, familiarize yourself with an editor to sketch the reaction schemes, and to export the scheme as a .png you may upload here (limit: 2MB). Some of them are compared [here](https://www.gunda.hu/dprogs/index.html). If your institution does not offer a campus license, e.g., [ChemDraw](https://chemdrawdirect.perkinelmer.cloud/js/sample/index.html#) and [Marvin](https://marvinjs-demo.chemaxon.com/latest/demo.html) offer sketchers with less functionality yet running from a web browser (no installation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question you pose is the work of [Stork and Dolfini](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja00901a061) that led to the synthesis of aspidospermine **7** and quebrachamine **9**. The aminoketone **1a** was condensed with either phenylhydrazine or o-methoxyphenylhydrazine to form the respective arylhydrazones **2a** and **2b**. Exposure of either hydrazone to hot acetic acid led to a "Fischer indole synthesis" that produced the indolenines **6a** and **6b**. Reduction of indolenine **6b** with LiAlH<sub>4</sub> followed by acetylation afforded d,l-aspidospermidine **7**, whose stereochemistry was not known at the time. Reduction of indolenine **6a** with KBH<sub>4</sub> effected reduction of immonium salt **8** (blue arrows) leading to d,l-quebrachamine **9**, 
One might ask why a normal Fischer indole synthesis did not occur by having the imine double bond of hydrazone **2** tautomerize toward the methylene group of the tricyclic ring moiety. My recollection, having been in this laboratory at the time, was that this issue was a problem when the sequence of reactions was run on the ketolactam **1b**. [@Waylander]

[image]

[G. Stork and J. E. Dolfini, *J. Am. Chem. Soc.*, *1963*, **85**, 2872.](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja00901a061)

Comment: If you thought that a Fischer indole synthesis was involved, you should have made some effort in that direction.

Comment: @user55119 *Speculation:* The OP did not recognize the tautomeric relationship between compounds **2** and **3**.

Comment: @user55119 Good answer. I was not aware of this work. Is it known whether the isomeric indole is also formed in the reaction from 1a?

Comment: @Waylander: After acetylation the paper states"...gave a crude material from which aspidospermine..." I suspect that some indole was formed. But then again, that was 58 years ago. My memory is good but not that good. ;)

Comment: @user55119  and the analytical methods of the time may have struggled to find it if it was present in small amounts

Comment: @Waylander: We had tlc and a 60 MHz NMR. Ketolactam 2b formed an indole. LiAlH4 reduction of the lactam would have given an authentic sample. I don't know if that was done. My previous quote, which was  carefully couched by the authors, makes me believe that the indole was in the crude product.

Comment: @user55119  I agree, I think it very likely some was formed. We need that keen project student to run the reaction and get an LCMS of the reaction mixture

Answer (score 3):

Fischer Indole for the first step looks possible depending on reaction conditions, but this [source](https://new.bhu.ac.in/Content/Syllabus/Syllabus_300620200422112348.pdf) states that the indole nucleus is not reduced by LiAlH4, nor do I recall ever seeing it done. Therefore I think what is happening is formation of the phenylhydrazone followed by reduction to the 1,2 di-substituted hydrazine.